# How to test a blender call when using blender as a module?

Tags: python

We have a simple class that does this:

```
...
   bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath="path_to_file"))
   bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath="path_to_saved_file")
...
```

I want to test that we have called the proper functions with the proper names.
I do not seem to find a way to do that.

We are using purest.

```
with mocker.patch("bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile") as mocked:
   ....
```

Gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'BPyOpsSubMod' object has no attribute 'save_as_mainfile'
```

My understanding that everything is a plugin and is initialised at runtime.
I tried to mock the `__init__` function with no luck because you do not know on which object to mock it, and some of them have it private (shock)..

I tried to do maybe to get out the information from the console, but with no luck aswel.

```
(Pdb) bpy.ops.console.copy()
*** RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.console.copy.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

What is the proper way to test that a call has been made to blender?